# How to see the setup of an OAuth Connected App

Tags: connected-apps, oauth

I am trying to figure out the setup of the integration with an external system. When I go into the user account being used as the integration user account I see the name of the application in the login history. However, I can't see an app by that name listed in the Connected Apps, or in the App Manager.

If I go into "Connected Apps OAuth Usage" I can see that app listed, along with the users who are using it. But that's all the details I can get regarding the app. The "Install" button is to the far right side (not the "Uninstall"), which confuses me even more because I wouldn't think that an app which is being used still needs to be installed. And that's about all the information I can get about it. Is there another location to see the details of this app ?

Comment: No, I can actually see the rows in the "OAuth Connected Apps" section of the user account. What I can't see is the actual app in the list of Connected Apps or in the Manage Apps list. I can see it in the "Connected Apps OAuth Usage" choice of the Setup menu, but that doesn't get me any details of the app, and I want to see the details of that app.

Answer (score 2):

Only the app you create your org shows up under the Manage > Apps. This where you build the connected app.

However, to manage the App policies you will have to install the app from the `Manage > Connected Apps OAuth Usage`

This is where you can set the Oauth policies and the Session Policies.

Comment: I think some of the things I would get if I were to get into policies would be Consumer Key and Consumer Secret. Why weren't they needed when the app was initially installed ? If I were to install it now and produce them would they be required next time my integration users which are currently using the app log in ? They're obviously not using it now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to get details of app as those are created in an org on which you might don't have rights. One thing you can do is to use that app in sandbox login sandbox while using that app and after that you can install that app in your sandbox if you find anything un-usual then you can block that app and can revoke all access token.

Edit

The Same I did with Salesforce CLI

[image]

After this I was able to edit it's policies
[image]

Why we can't see the app?

For OAuth It's not necessary the app to be installed in your Org. You just need to authorise it very first time. Might [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/245017/56744) helps you to get a clear idea on OAuth

Comment: I have admin rights in the org, so I would think I'd see it at least in the Manage Apps list. Also - why does it show the "Install" button to the far right in the "Connected Apps OAuth Usage" list if we are already using it ?

Comment: so this is an app which was installed into the org for the purpose of OAuth, but it doesn't actually show up in the Connected Apps ? Was it most likely a Salesforce app ? Is it likely in my App Manager list under a different name as was also indicated might be the case ?

Comment: Yes this is a standard Salesforce Connected app used in SFDX commands and it was not visible in org utill I click on install in Connected App Oauth Usage.

Comment: So what exactly is gained if you were to 'Install' it ? Is it just a matter of applying restrictions such as IP restrictions ? Would it produce a Consumer Key and Consumer Secret ? If so, would they then be required to use it ? Is it required in order for the app to allow API POST calls ? I want my users to be able to create records via API. Is it required to 'Install' an OAuth app so it appears in the Connected Apps in order for them to do that ?

Comment: Yes after installing this you will be able to apply security restriction. I don't think you need a separate clientId and Key If you want then you need to create your own connected app, otherwise you can use the already exist connected app based on permission it can allow you to make POST API calls

Comment: thank you again. I really appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

You want `Create > Apps...` , that's the menu tree for managing apps you develop.

The `Install` button only shows up for us under `Manage > Connected Apps oAuth Usage` when the app was installed and then uninstalled. If it shows up for an already installed app, it might be a different app. The app identity is not based on the display name you see on the list of apps.

See [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=connected_app_manage.htm&type=5) for more info

Comment: thank you very much for your insight here. I'm kinda answering below. I didn't want to write it twice and confuse things.